# Chaos theory combined with RSA and/or other cryptosystems?

Tags: encryption

What are your thoughts on this? Are there any complications a designer of such a cryptosystem might face? Or, a better way to put it.. are there obvious drawbacks with chaotic functions when using them for cryptographic purposes?

Comment: It is not clear how Chaos theory could be combined with RSA. Please ask concise questions "what are your thoughts on this" is literally asking for opinion based answers. The final sentence is a bit more succinct but that overlooks [the many Q/A's that have been written about using chaos theory](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?q=chaos)

Comment: Chaos theory does not compete with wide-trail, discrete-log, integer factorization, lattice reduction, hash-preimage, error-correcting codes, in any aspect. Those familiar with the current status of cryptography frowns upon chaos theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or, a better way to put it.. are there obvious drawbacks with chaotic functions when using them for cryptographic purposes?

The obvious drawback is that it adds an unclear amount of value, while appealing to notions that are frankly mostly used informally by amateurs.
As an example, RSA (when parameterized and implemented correctly) is secure.
What would adding chaos theory to it even add? Make it "double secure"?

Cryptography works best when one can formalize precise hardness assumptions, and then tightly connect the security of a cryptosystem to those hardness assumptions.
For example

> **Factoring Hardness Assumption**: Factoring an $n$-bit semi-prime takes $L_n[1/3, (64/9)^{1/3}]$ time, using [L-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-notation).

> **Security of RSA**: Provided the factoring assumption holds, RSA cannot be broken in time less than $T$.

I won't try to compute $T$ (and don't think people can, as breaking RSA does not reduce to factoring iirc). But this is the goal of a lot of research in public-key crypto, and this kind of statement was used to select parameters for the post-quantum replacement for RSA, namely Kyber (now ML-KEM).

What would it look like to do something for a chaotic system?
Say you have a chaotic map $f: X\to X$.
You could do something like compute its iterate $f^{(n)}(x) = \overbrace{f(f(\dots f(x)\dots))}^{n\text{ times}}$.
A standard cryptographic construction might be something like

> **Chaotic Encryption**: Let $X$ be an abelian group.
>
> 1. Key Gen: Sample $k\gets X$ uniformly
> 2. Enc: Sample $i\gets X$ uniformly, and output $(i, m+f^{(n)}(k+i))$ for the message $m$
> 3. Dec: On input $(i, c)$, output $c - f^{(n)}(k+i)$

This is a correct cryptosystem. Provided $f^{(n)}(x)$ is a weak PRF, it will be secure up to $\approx\sqrt{|X|}$ queries (by the birthday bound).
So everything is fine provided $f^{(n)}$ satisfies some cryptographic property. Note here that $n$ is a scheme parameter, so you can choose it as high as you want for $f^{(n)}$ to be a weak PRF (though larger $n$ is less efficient).

Is there reason to think that this is the case?
Not that I know of. Most amateurs assume that chaotic systems satisfy the required cryptographic properties for informal reasons, and build broken cryptosystems.
For example, the Wikipedia on Chaos theory contains the following under "Cryptography"

> From a wider perspective, without loss of generality, the similarities between the chaotic maps and the cryptographic systems is the main motivation for the design of chaos based cryptographic algorithms.[124] One type of encryption, secret key or symmetric key, relies on diffusion and confusion, which is modeled well by chaos theory.[126] Another type of computing, DNA computing, when paired with chaos theory, offers a way to encrypt images and other information.[127] **Many of the DNA-Chaos cryptographic algorithms are proven to be either not secure, or the technique applied is suggested to be not efficient.[128][129][130]**

This has been my experience with people who try to discuss chaos theory for cryptography.
Very often the papers are published in non-cryptographic journals, by people who do not know how to evaluate cryptographic systems.